# How to get Twitter suspended user details

Tags: api, twitter, user-accounts

Is there any way via which we can get suspended Twitter account details? I searched it on Internet but did not get anything relevant.

I wonder if there is a Twitter API or APIs other than Twitter which can help retrieving suspended user details. Details like the one which Twitter returns from its various API end-points.

This is my first experience with Twitter.

Answer (score 4):

The call you want is [GET users/lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/lookup)

From the Twitter API docs:

> GET users / show is used to retrieve a single user object.
>
> If a requested user is unknown, suspended, or deleted, then that user
>   will not be returned in the results list.

Comment: For suspended users "lookup" will simply return the following error, so it's not the right answer. 'errors': [{'code': 17, 'message': 'No user matches for specified terms.'}]}

Answer (score 2):

You can try the API call: '[/1.1/users/show.json](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-show)'

If the user profile has been suspended, you will get response of the form:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [code] => 63
    [message] => User has been suspended.
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In TwitterAPI it's not possible. There are only two ways to retrieve user info: users/show which gives more details and users/lookup used for bulk requests (e.g. many ids). In the case of a suspended user, "lookup" will return the following error for a given ID:

```
api = TwitterAPI.TwitterAPI(... auth params ...)
api.request('users/lookup', {"user_id":"12345"})
{'errors': [{'code': 17, 'message': 'No user matches for specified terms.'}]}
```

While "show" will at least tell you that a user is suspended, which is more useful, but still no details about the user will be provided

```
api = TwitterAPI.TwitterAPI(... auth params ...)
api.request('users/show', {"user_id":"12345"})
{'errors': [{'code': 63, 'message': 'User has been suspended.'}]}
```

It's kind of awkward. @Twitter could've provided at least a screen name in this case.